# Manual calculation from VAR to SVAR and IRF

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, vector-autoregression

I want to estimate a SVAR model but the problem is I have multiple samples and I want to pool them together (e.g. I have multiple patients, each patient with two times series which are the endogenous variables in my model). So what I have done now is to first estimate a VAR model for these patients assuming that they share the same parameters using a Bayesian approach (I am unable to perform this using the VAR package in R as far as I know).

Having done that, what I need to do next is to transform the model into the structural form and then estimate the IRF. In R you can simply input the VAR object you estimated directly into the SVAR function and it'll do the rest. But since I don't have a VAR object, what alternatives do I have? Is there a way to construct my own VAR object with what I have estimated? Or do I have to somehow do this manually (seems like a tall order)?

Comment: Constructing your own VAR object (perhaps missing some irrelevant elements) might be one of the quickest solutions.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks. It doesn't look that easy with all these nested objects (lm)..

Comment: Check out if you really need all of them. Yet you have more detailed knowledge of this than I do, so my hunch may be wrong.

Comment: @RichardHardy It looks like it might indeed be possible using the script here [https://rdrr.io/cran/vars/src/R/SVAR.R](https://rdrr.io/cran/vars/src/R/SVAR.R)